# Java util Timer not working correctly

Tags: java, timer

I was wondering if someone might be able to see what I had done wrong here. I am trying to create a timer which will increment the count variable by 1 every second and print it out on the console. However, it prints the first number and then stops and I am not sure what is going on.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class TimerTest  {

    private Timer timer;
    public int count = 0;

    public TimerTest() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerListener(), 1000);
    }

    private class TimerListener extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new TimerTest();
    }
}
```

I did find some other questions like this but none of their solutions made any difference to the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your scheduling only runs the task once. You need to add a parameter to use the method [schedule(TimerTask task,
            long delay,
            long period)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29):

```
timer.schedule(new TimerListener(), 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: @MichaelShort, As a new user, i think we should notify you. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think this answer satisfied your question. There is a tick mark in the left side right below the upvote-downvote icon

Comment: @Michael, you can refer Timer.java class to know more about schedule(...) overloaded methods.